# Why is mypy finding "no type hints or library stubs" for any of my imports?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm working on a code base that has a lot of type hints written by a previous developer. At some point I noticed that these hints were not getting type-checked, and that I needed to add a step to the build if I wanted them checked. I'm comfortable in python but have never used type hints, so I did a lot of reading about them, and I still have a lot to understand. Eventually I conclude that mypy is the main program used to type-check these type hints. So I pip installed mypy and ran `mypy .`. I got a lot of errors like these;

```
error: Skipping analyzing 'setuptools': found module but no type hints or library stubs
error: Skipping analyzing 'numpy': found module but no type hints or library stubs
error: Skipping analyzing 'tensorflow.compat.v1': found module but no type hints or library stubs
error: Skipping analyzing 'tensorflow': found module but no type hints or library stubs
```

I was quite surprised that these were considered errors by default, because everything I have read about type hinting emphasizes that they are optional. So my first question is, why does mypy treat the above as show-stopping errors rather than simple warnings?

Then I google the error message and find [this page](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-type-hints-for-third-party-library) of the mypy documentation. This is arguably pretty clear, but what confuses me is that it seems to indicate that this error is a big problem that should be resolved. It gives multiple options for resolving it of increasing effort levels before they finally tell you the CLI flag that will silence all the errors. Surely most projects would import libraries that don't use type hints, and would need to use this flag?

Because of these clues, I decide that I should probably keep trying, and look for the packages. The next thing that confused me is that it seems to be failing to find type hints for *all* of my imports. I don't expect more obscure libraries to have written type hints, but surely somebody has written them for numpy, or pytest? The documentation says I should look for the packages by appending `types-` to the main package name, so I run `pip install types-numpy`, but it doesn't find anything.

Now I'm starting to wonder if maybe my machine is failing to connect to some kind of service, like whatever "typeshed" is? Pip can find packages just fine, but maybe typeshed is a separate protocol that is currently down or something? Or does it have to do with the fact that I'm using an older version of python (3.6)? I decide to manually search for the packages [here](https://pypi.org/search/?c=Typing%20%3A%3A%20Typed&o=&q=numpy&page=1), but I don't see almost any that start with `types-`.

So my overall question is, **is something weird going on, or should I just run mypy with the `--ignore-missing-imports` flag and move on?**

Comment: I'm currently facing this issue with numpy specifically. numpy 1.20.0 seems to be more compatible with mypy than previous versions. Two release candidates are [available](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tags) with a final release being imminent. It can be compiled from source. `--ignore-missing-imports` is one solution until these packages are more widely available.

Comment: The authoritative documentation regarding this issue is present here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html Apparently this is a complex issue and thus requires reading the whole page I have shared to understand why this issue occurs and what to do about it.

Comment: After `myp --install-types` and `pip install types-requests` did not resolve the issue, I tried generating the typing (stubs) for `requests` automatically using: [MonkeyType](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType). I created an `eg.py` file with content: `import requests` and then ran: `pip install MonkeyType`, then `monkeytype run eg.py` however that yielded: `AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute '__qualname__'`. I am not yet sure whether this is an issue with MonkeyType, or incompatibility of `requests` with typing. Would be nice if someone can follow up.

Comment: Did you find a working solution for requests?

Answer (score 12):

This error is because `mypy` was not able to find the module you are trying to import, whether it comes bundled with type hints or not. Also, ensure that your imports doesn't have a typo.

You can resolve the issue by running the suggested pip command or commands. Alternatively, you can use `--install-types` to install all known missing stubs: `mypy --install-types`

Comment: The error message says "found module but no type hints or library stubs", so I would hope it has found the modules. Also I know the modules are installed because the code using the module runs as expected.

Comment: Did you try running that command and issue still persist?

Comment: I just tried running `mypy --install-types`; the command exited with a return code of 0, but there was no output. Running mypy still gives "found module but no type hints or library stubs".

Comment: I'm getting this same error with the `requests` library. Running `mypy --install-types` returns with a 0 code but does nothing. I even manually installed `types-requests`, but get the same issue.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716482/error-skipping-analyzing-flask-mysqldb-found-module-but-no-type-hints-or-lib. Which gives a detailed explanation. Hope it helps!